# ASIHttPRequest didReceiveData- how to populate responseData, responseString?

Tags: asihttprequest

I'm setting the delegate and implementing didReceiveData for one type of request, but for others I just want to be able to set the responseData, as happens in the regular case.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a name other than 'didReceiveData' for your function, and use request.didReceiveDataSelector = @selector(yourSelector); when you create the request where you need the didReceiveData information.